# get rid of file:///c:// in HTML file

Tags: html

I save my html in my local driver (c:/).

I do the next in my html file:

```
<td><a href="www.google.com">Google</a></td>
```

When I open it, and click on the link, it enter to: `file:///C:/www.google.com`

How can I get rid of the `file://c:/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `http://` in front of the domain name. Otherwise it links to a file named "www.google.com" in the same directory as the HTML file.

```
<td><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need http:// before your link.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
```

Otherwise it is looking for a file called www.google.com on your server!